# SOAP Spring Client Request over https and through firewall

Tags: java, spring, ssl, websphere, soap-client

It has been a while since I wrote a SOAP client, but I am trying to write a client that connects / consumes an external SOAP service across https and through a firewall.

I have manually pulled the wsdl and schemas and used Eclipse Web Service Client feature to generate web service code. I am calling the client code through a get request at moment just to see if I can even connect to the WS. I can browse the WSDL in Chrome\IE and able to use ReadyApi to test the connection outside of Java and RAD/WebSphere.

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();     
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.complianceservice.client");
    try {
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return marshaller;
}
@Bean
public VendorClient vendorClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    VendorClient client = new VendorClient ();
    client.setDefaultUri("https://webservice.vendor.com/WebServices/productServices.svc?wsdl");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}
```

This will call the client service code...

```
@GetMapping(value = "/health")
public String getHealth() throws ResponseException {
    Response response = vendorComplianceService.processHealth();
    return response!= null?"Health, OK":"Problem detected";
}

@Override
public MessageResponse processHealth() throws ResponseException {
    try {
        GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse response = vendorClient.getGetDaysUntilPasswordExpires();
        if (response != null){
            MessageResponse myResponse = new MessageResponse();
        //set something
            return myResponse;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ResponseException(e);
    }       
    return null;
}

public GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse getGetDaysUntilPasswordExpires( ){

    GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires requestPayload = new GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires();
    requestPayload.setContext(healthClientContext());   
    log.info("Requesting expire info for :" + clientContext.getUserID());       
    GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse response = (GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive("https://webservice.vendor.com/WebServices/IAccount/GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires", requestPayload                     
            );
    return response;
}
```

This will just timeout looking for a connection response from the server because our firewall is blocking it.

How do I tell this client code to use proxy settings to get through our Firewall in Java/Spring? In REST I am able to specify an httpclient that uses Proxy credential provider with an ssl connection socket factory.  I am not sure how to do this with the SOAP client that uses the WebServiceTemplate to marshal, send and receive. Is this even a good idea?

Also how can I log or view the actual SOAP request to make sure I am sending proper format?

For those familiar with WebSphere, how can I ensure the remote certificates are properly installed and usable?

Comment: Is this "Traditional" WebSphere, or WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: Traditional WAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of @dbreaux help to add the CA to WAS and the following solved the issue .

In the AppConfig, I added this bean ...

```
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(){
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    MessageFactory msgFactory = null;
    try {
        msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.DEFAULT_SOAP_PROTOCOL);
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SaajSoapMessageFactory newSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(msgFactory);
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageFactory(newSoapMessageFactory);
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
    return webServiceTemplate; 
}

//and then wired into the client component and set system properties for https proxy

public GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse getGetDaysUntilPasswordExpires(  ){
    System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", HTTPS_PROXY_HOST );  
    System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", HTTPS_PROXY_PORT);

    System.getProperties().put("https.proxyUser", HTTPS_PROXY_USER );  
    System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPassword", HTTPS_PROXY_PASSWORD);
    GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires requestPayload = new GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires();
    requestPayload.setContext( healthClientContext());

    log.info("Requesting expire info for :" + healthClientContext.getUserID()); 
    GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse response = (GetDaysUntilPasswordExpiresResponse) webServiceTemplate 
            .marshalSendAndReceive(
                    VENDOR_WS_URL+"/Account"
                    ,requestPayload 
                    ,new SoapActionCallback(VENDOR_WS_NAMESPACE_URL+"/IAccount/GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires"){
                        @Override
                        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message)
                                throws IOException {
                            SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
                            soapMessage.setSoapAction(VENDOR_WS_NAMESPACE_URL+"/IAccount/GetDaysUntilPasswordExpires");   
                        }
                    }
            );
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the last part of your question, you'll typically select the "CellDefaultTrustStore" and "Retrieve from port", specifying the remote server and port:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/usec_sslretrievesignercert.html

(I don't have an answer on the proxy question.)

Comment: I had more than one but I when I saw and used the "Default" truststore listed under Security> SSL certificate and key management > SSL Config >Default settings, that was the correct keystore to import the root CA.